# Let $H\le G$ of index $3$. Prove that either $H\unlhd G$, or that $H$ has a subgroup $N$ of index $2$ in $H$ such that $N\unlhd G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$ of index $3$. Prove that either $H$ is normal, or
that $H$ has a subgroup $N$ of index $2$ in $H$ such that $N$ is normal in $G$.

All I could show is that if $H$ is not normal then $2||G|$ and so $2| |H|$. I am not sure how to proceed

Comment: Hint: Take the permutation representation on the cosets of $H$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Could you elaborate? Do you mean $G$ acts on the set of cosets of $H$?I still dont see what I should do next.

Comment: Not really. The proof is about three lines long. I've given you the first line. I cannot give anything more without giving you the answer.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I think I got it. The group action induces a hoomorphism from $G \to S_3$. Thus, by first isomorphism theorem the kernel of that homomorphism is not only normal but has index $3!$, we know that the kernel is contained in $H$ as only elements of $H$ fix $H$ in the action. Thus the kernel is normal, and must have index $2$ in $H$. IS this correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But you can do slightly better, see my answer (soon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a subgroup of index $3$. Let $\phi:G\to S_3$ be the permutation action on the cosets of $H$. The kernel $N$ of this action is a normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$ (the core of $H$ in $G$), and has index dividing $3!=6$. If $N=H$ then $H\lhd G$ and we are done. If $|G:N|=6$ (the only other option as $\mathrm{im}(\phi)$ is a subgroup of $S_3$ of order a multiple of $3$) then $G/N\cong S_3$. In particular, $G/N$, and hence $G$, have a subgroup $N_0$ of index $2$. The subgroup $N$ is then $H\cap N_0$.